# How to get a specific JSON data value from a URL?

Tags: android, json, cloud

I cannot get a specific value form the JSON data. Lets say i have JSON data like the following  https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/494244/fields/1.json?api_key=3O8HR1YR38GCGD31&results=1 . I am able to get the JSON data visible but unable to get the specific data i require.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static Button click;
public static TextView data;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    data=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.fetcheddata);

    click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fetchData process=new fetchData();
            process.execute();
```

fetchData class

```
public class fetchData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
String data="";
int dataParsed=0;
String singleParsed="";
String entryId="";
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    try {
        URL url=new URL("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/494244/fields/1.json?api_key=3O8HR1YR38GCGD31&results=2");

        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line="";
        while(line!=null){
            line=bufferedReader.readLine();
            data=data+line;
        }
        JSONObject object=new JSONObject(data);
        JSONObject feeds=object.getJSONObject("feeds");
        entryId = feeds.getString("entry_id");

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    MainActivity.data.setText(this.entryId
    );
```

Please help on how i could get the specific value. For example "entry_id" in the feeds array in the JSON data link i have provided. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Well... `feeds` is an Array and not an Object. So you will need to change the:

```
object.getJSONObject("feeds")
```

to:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("feeds")
```

Finally, to be able to get your `entry_id`

```
jsonArray.getInt("entry_id")
```

You need to check the type of what you whant to get from the JSON and use the appropriate get method.

**Edit:**

Sorry, as this is an array, you have to loop through it... something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray().length(); i++ { jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("entry_id"); }
```

Comment: There is an error saying that getInt(int) in JSONArray cannot be applied to java.lang.String. Why is that?

Comment: how should i setText to display it?

Comment: You set the entryId inside the loop and setText in the postExecute

Comment: I did that. But its not working. Really sorry. Im totally new to this.